# Blackberry: Create a popup Dialog

Tags: blackberry, customdialog

i would like to know how can i create a custom popup in blakcberry in order to set the Fields in this way:

------Text---------

Button1   Button2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that extends `Popup` .

In this class use your own manager

in your case you need

one `vertical field manager`

add a text into it

prepare a `horizontal field manager` 
  add both buttons into it

add that `horizontal field manager` into `vertical field manager`

And add `vertical field manager` in your screen

Comment: The 1st step probably not needed because the default manager is VFM