# popup window in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I create a popup window when I click a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at these links,u can get ideas:

[Blackberry: Create a popup Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169810/blackberry-create-a-popup-dialog)

[BlackBerry programing - create borderless popup screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216382/blackberry-programing-create-borderless-popup-screen)

Moreover u can search stackoverflow to get more answers...
:)

Answer (score 10):

You can use a few different methods, status to inform the user (default 2 seconds display):

```
Status.show("Hello!");
```

Set your own display time:

```
Status.show("Hello!", 5000)
```

or a modal dialog:

```
Dialog.inform("Hello!");
```

a dialog with a response:

```
 int response = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Continue?");
                switch (response) {
                    case Dialog.YES:
                        //do something
                    default:
                        //do nothing
                }
```

or for a full actual PopupScreen you create a popup class:

```
public class MyPopup extends PopupScreen{
public MyPopup() {
    super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.FOCUSABLE);
    add(new LabelField("Hello!"));
}
```

}

and push it to the stack like you would with a normal MainScreen class:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyPopup());
```